# How to add an end screen in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0

Right, the game I've got is a 2D car racing game. I have implemented the finish line image in the game and so on. And I've got it as a separate sprite sheet. Here's the code I'm attempting to alter in such a way, that 'If car1blue intersects finishLine1, end game.' But I just can't seem to get it right. Here's the code I'm attempting to alter;

```
if (IntersectPixels(destinationBlueRect, finishLine1TextureData, finishLine1Rectangle, finishLine1TextureData))
{
    blueHit = true;                 
}
```

It would be even better if you could show me how to add an end game message saying 'Player 1 wins' (when car crosses finishline1) and end game roughly three seconds after that?

Any help is welcome please (I'm a newbie). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to implement this [Game State Management](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) system, as for your delay:

```
float delayTime = 3000;// Time to delay in milliseconds
float delayBuffer = 0;// This will count how much time has passed

// In your Update method
if (blueHit) {// You should change this to whatever way you find if someone has won the game
    if (delayBuffer < delayTime) {
        delayBuffer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    } else {
        // Show the last screen
    }
}
```